# Artifactory PRO: Disabling license expiration notice

Tags: artifactory, license-key

We're running Artifactory Pro 4.11.0 (planning to upgrade to 6.1.0) and our license has just expired.

All users are seeing a notice stating:

```
Your Artifactory license has expired. To renew your license please contact sales@jfrog.com
```

How can this notice be disabled?

EDIT: We do NOT plan to renew the license - our current license grants us usage of Artifactory up to v6.1.0

Comment: I don't think there's a way to do this, short of modifying the responses via a reverse proxy or something hacky like that. Will the message really cause that much of a problem for you while you're in the process of making the upgrade? If so, you might try contacting JFrog support and explaining the situation, and they might be able to provide you with a 4.x trial license to tide you over.

Comment: Thank you @DarthFennec - I've just added some information to my question. We won't renew the license, at least not in the short term.